# laravel echo vue websocket https

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sockets

I developed an application with laravel (back) and vuejs (front).

I'm trying to add sockets to send notifications on the front side.

I think there is a config missing on the apache side but I can't find the solution.

I have a front side error:

> "app.js:401205 WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://appname:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: "

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'https://' + window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    transports: ['websocket']
});
```

apache httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName appname
    ServerAlias *.appname
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/appname/public

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/cert/certificat.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/key/private.key"
    
    <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/appname/public">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I had tested and validated with pusher that everything was working fine but
i want to use redis. Only this part is not working.

I really need help please.

Thank you.

Comment: is your laravel-echo-server started?

Comment: Hello, yes Laravel echo is started.

Comment: import this line to index.html         <script src="https://yourip:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: I still have the same problem. laravel-echo-server receives the event, but my page does not receive anything

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem.
this is my code
i use  laravel echo library

```
import Vue from 'vue'        
import VueEcho from 'vue-echo-laravel';



  Vue.use(VueEcho, {
                broadcaster: 'socket.io',
                host: "http://192.168.21.100:6001,
            });
            this.$echo.channel('messages').listen('.newMessage', (payload) => {
                console.log("messages ", payload);
               
            });
```

insert this line to  index.html

```
<script src="http://192.168.21.100:6001:socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: than you for your answer but always same.. no event in front.
when I put my ip (local), I have an error because it asks me to put https (I am in https (local)

Comment: are the vue join the laravel-echo?